# Cursor changes to default after using history.replaceState() in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, macos, safari

I'm building a website with a slideshow and using `history.replaceState()` to add a hash and counting number to the URL when clicking through the images.

When hovering over the the "next" button of the slideshow, the cursor is changed to a custom arrow using CSS. When I click the button `history.replaceState()` is called—what resets the cursor to the default. As soon as I move the cursor a bit, the intended arrow appears again.

This happens only in Safari—Chrome and Firefox are working fine. Any ideas on why this happens and how to avoid it?

Here is a snippet of the problem. It needs to be saved to its own file, since you can't change the history state of the parent from within an iframe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #click {
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1em;
    }
    
    #click:hover {
      cursor: crosshair;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="click">
    Hover and click me and change history!
  </div>
  <div id="hash">
    No hash
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;

    document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function() {
      history.replaceState(null, null, '#' + i);
      document.querySelector('#hash').innerHTML = "We now have a hash: " + document.location.hash;
      i++;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please show more code so that your question can be answered with the most appropriate answer.

Comment: I added a snippet directly to my question so it's easier to save and test it in its own window.

Comment: TBH this just sounds like a Safari bug.

Comment: You could probably work around this by reapplying a style that sets the cursor just after `replaceState` is called.